# SharePoint Workflow not visible to some users

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 WF on a list (SharePoint 2016 on-Prem).

Under the following scenario, the WF is **NOT** visible to the user

- User has Full Control on List
- User has only Read permissions at the site Level (Visitors group)

Under the following scenario, the WF **IS** visible to the user

- User has Full Control on List
- User has Contribute permissions to the site (Members group)

I don't want the user with more than Read permissions on the site. But do want them to be able to see the workflows on the List and invoke them.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a list workflow instead of the site workflow.

Comment: It is already a list workflow and not a site workflow.

Comment: As per my test, if a user has full control on a list and read permission level on the site, he is able to see the workflow set on the list via List > Workflow Settings. So, what do you mean by "see the workflows"?

Comment: This is what I would expect also. But as that user, if you look at workflows available to start on an item, it does not show up. If you add the same user to the Members list on the site, the workflow appears.